# How to import ErrorUtils in React Native

Tags: react-native

- RN version: 0.50
- Testing on Android, haven't tested on iOS

I am trying to use `ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler` as described in this github issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1194

However, what is not clear from the issue is how to import ErrorUtils.  It's not in the react documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.50/getting-started.html

Previously, in RN 0.41, I was able to import ErrorUtils with `import ErrorUtils from "ErrorUtils";`  However, in 0.50 I am getting a red react popup with the following message when I try to import ErrorUtils like this:

```
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false' failed to load.
```

I've also tried `import { ErrorUtils } from 'react-native';` but it doesn't seem to exist there.  The error is:

```
Cannot read property 'setGlobalHandler' of undefined
```

How do I properly import ErrorUtils in RN 0.50?

Answer (score 8):

ErrorUtils is a global variable, therfore it doesn't need to be imported. You can verify this with `console.log(global.ErrorUtils)`

However it is exported as module anyways ([here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1151c096dab17e5d9a6ac05b61aacecd4305f3db/Libraries/vendor/core/ErrorUtils.js#L25)). The comment there also has more information why it is done this way.

You can import the module like this:

`import ErrorUtils from 'ErrorUtils';`

Comment: I was importing like `import React, { ErrorUtils } from 'react';` in the root component and didn't get an error but the root wouldn't render at all. Removing the `, { ErrorUtils }` from the import made it render :shrug:

Answer (score 3):

For anyone on RN61+, you should no longer import the module as you will experience the following error in the running metro bundler:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module `ErrorUtils`
```

Instead, just use the module without importing as this is a global variable, as stated by [leo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54988592/6356509)

Answer (score 1):

I did created a global.d.ts to define a global variable,

```
interface Global {

   ErrorUtils: {
      setGlobalHandler: any
      reportFatalError: any
      getGlobalHandler: any
   }

}

declare var global: Global
```

then, at where you are trying to use it, simply

```
global.ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler(xxxx)
```